# Converting large database of addresses and associated data into point shapefile within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I have a large Excel spreadsheet of addresses and project data. I would like to automatically convert this into a point shapefile based on the addresses.

Since these are not coordinates and are addresses, how do I do this using ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of converting physical addresses to locations on earth (and viceversa) is known as geocoding. [Here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geocoding/what-is-geocoding.htm) is a good read on what geocoding is.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at [Geocoding a table of addresses in ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/geocoding-a-table-of-addresses-in-arcmap.htm) for a detailed guide on how to convert your Excel spreadsheet with addresses to a Shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has a tool for geocoding of addresses in Excel. Actually, two tools. One is for [batch processing](https://www.yaddress.net/BatchProcessing) of Excel files, and another is an [Excel add-in](https://www.yaddress.net/Excel) for processing within the spreadsheet.